# Using react-native-mapbox-gl on IOS

Tags: react-native, mapbox, react-native-ios, mapbox-gl

Im getting this error when I try to run on xcode:

ld: library not found for -lRCTMapboxGL

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

When I do run-ios I get this kinda generic error:

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/InterfaseCity.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

I tried installing with pod and also manual
https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/blob/master/ios/install.md

When I search my node_module/@mapbox folder I do not see anything similar to RCTMapboxGL on the files.

any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I had to remove the library inside Build Phases and then follow the instructions for iOS.

It seems that react native tried to link the MapBox library unsuccessfully, creating some garbage.